# DIU not going beyond 4

Tags: azure-data-factory

For a simple Copy activity that copies from ADLS Gen1 to Gen2, I set DIU to 32 but this doesn't reflect when I run the copy activity. 
If I set DIU to Auto, even then the DIU is always 4 but never more than that.  (ParallelCopies setting do reflect properly)
Region for Gen1, Gen2, Default Azure IR--> East US 2

Attaching screenshots with some details.

Any suggestions please?

[image: Copy - Input and Output results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to copy 1GB data, thus somehow DIU never crossed 4.

But when I tried to copy 10GB data, I noticed DIU started scaling up beyond 4.

Comment: If it's Auto , then only it will suffice the task of 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

The range of DIU setting is `2-256`.However, specific behaviors of DIU in different copy scenarios are different even though you set the number as you want.

Please see the table [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#data-integration-units) here,especially for the below part:

[image]

DIU has some limitations as you seen,so you could choose the optimal setting with your custom scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this document already. I have set Copy behaviour to Preserve hierarchy. I tried copying from ADL Gen1 to gen2, ADL Gen2 to Gen2, SQL to SQL but every time DIU is just 4, not beyond that. I don't see the same problem in another Azure subscription though.

Comment: @SomeGuy ok,then maybe you could contact ADF team to verify the root cause for this strange behavior.

Comment: @JayGong I have similar issue(tried to increase DIU to 16), in my case i am trying to copy data from GCP (bigquery) to Blob Storage with 2.8 gb data and 12 mi records also with Preserve hierarchy still there is no increase in DIU. Any tips on how to fix this issue?